# How to stack Media Query grid elements on top of each other when the screen size is reduced?

Tags: html, css, grid

So im trying to copy the grailed add a listing website, now I'm just up to making my page responsive and have the grid elements stacked on top of one another when I reduce the screen size just like the grailed website ([screenshot of responsive grailed page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N3xrV.png))

I've tried creating a media query and playing around with a single grid template column but some elements seem like they are still in a two-column grid.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
}

.first {
  display: flex;
  padding-right: 7rem;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  padding-left: 7rem;
  justify-content: space-between;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.header {
  padding-top: 1rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.9rem;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #eeeeee;
}

.logo {
  height: 1.4rem;
  width: 9rem;
  margin-right: 1.5rem;
}

.search {
  height: 2.3rem;
  width: 29rem;
  border: 0.1rem solid black;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 4.1rem;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #eeeeee;
  color: black;
}

.header a,
.navbar a {
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  font-weight: 560;
  color: black;
}

.header a:hover,
.navbar a:hover {
  color: blue;
}

.second a {
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
}

.navbar a {
  margin-right: 1.7rem;
  margin-left: 1.7rem;
  padding-top: 0.7rem;
  padding-bottom: 0.7rem;
}

.line {
  background-color: black;
  height: 0.3rem;
  width: 2rem;
  margin: 0.1rem;
}

.addListing {
  display: grid;
  align-content: center;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  grid-template-columns: 28em 28rem;
  margin-top: 2rem;
}

h3 {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
}

.item-name,
.item-size {
  grid-column: 2/3;
}

.note {
  grid-column: 1/2;
  font-size: 0.7rem;
  line-height: 2;
}

.addListing select,
.form-input {
  height: 2.3rem;
  width: 26rem;
  margin-bottom: 1rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.description {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  height: 9rem;
  padding: 1.5rem;
  font-size: 0.9rem;
}

.form-start {
  justify-self: start;
}

.form-end {
  justify-self: end;
}

#payment,
#shipping,
.price {
  grid-column: 1/2;
}

#tips,
#ship-tips {
  grid-column: 2/3;
  justify-self: end;
  font-weight: lighter;
}

#tips a,
#ship-tips a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: blue;
}

.shipping-desc {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  font-size: 1rem;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

label {
  font-weight: 580;
}

.country,
.second-col {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
  padding-top: 1rem;
  width: 26rem;
  border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #eeeeee;
  /* width: 26rem;
 padding-bottom: 1rem;
 padding-top: 1rem;
 border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #eeeeee; */
}

.second-col {
  /* moves second column to the end of the grid */
  justify-self: end;
}

.country label,
.second-col label {
  margin-right: auto;
  align-self: center;
}

input[type="checkbox"] {
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
}


/* .country input {
 height: 2.3rem;
 margin-left: 3rem;
} */


/* .second-col {
 display: flex;
 justify-content: flex-end;
 border-bottom: 0.1rem solid #eeeeee;
 padding-bottom: 1rem;
 padding-top: 1rem;
} */

.photos-heading {
  padding-top: 2rem;
}

.image-upload>input {
  display: none;
}

.orig-grid {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  padding-bottom: 1rem;
}

.images {
  display: grid;
  justify-items: stretch;
  justify-content: stretch;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
}

.pic-one {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  grid-row: 1/3;
}

.top-row {
  justify-self: end;
}

.bottom-row {
  align-self: end;
  justify-self: right;
}

.publish {
  grid-column: 1/3;
  height: 4rem;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
}

.footer {
  display: flex;
  padding-top: 2.5rem;
  padding-bottom: 1.6rem;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}

.footer-links {
  display: flex;
  margin-right: auto;
  font-size: 0.8rem;
  align-items: center;
}

.footer-links a,
.footer-socials a,
.footer-socials p {
  margin-right: 0.8rem;
  margin-left: 0.8rem;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}

.footer-socials {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.copyright {
  font-size: 0.8rem;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .addListing {
    grid-template-rows: 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr 1fr;
    grid-template-columns: 1fr;
    grid-template-areas: "heading-one" "heading-two" "categories" "name-item" "des-select" "enter-size" "des-note" "color" "des-color" "condition" "condition-select" "desc" "input-desc" "payment" "tips" "input-price" "shipping" "ship-tips" "ship-desc";
    background-color: pink;
  }
  /* h3,
 .item-name,
 .item-size,
 .note,
 select,
 .form-input,
 .description,
 #payment,
 #shipping,
 .price,
 #tips,
 #ship-tips,
 .shipping-desc,
 .country,
 .publish {
  grid-column: auto;
  grid-row: auto;
 } */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8" />
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" />
  <title>Micro components</title>
</head>

<body>
  <header class="header">
    <div class="first">
      <img src="grailed.png" alt="" class="logo" />
      <form action="">
        <input type="text" placeholder="Search" class="search" />
        <button type="submit">SEARCH</button>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="second">
      <a href="">SHOP</a>
      <a href="">SELL</a>
      <a href="">READ</a>
      <a href="">FOR YOU</a>
      <a href="">♥️</a>
    </div>
  </header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <a href="">DESIGNERS</a>
    <a href="">BROWSE BY CATEGORY⬇</a>
    <a href="">SNEAKERS</a>
    <a href="">FOOTWEAR</a>
    <a href="">TOPS</a>
    <a href="">OUTERWEAR</a>
    <a href="">STAFF PICKS</a>
    <a href="">COLLECTIONS</a>
    <a href="">WOMENSWEAR</a>
  </nav>
  <!-- <div class="hamburger">
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
   <div class="line"></div>
  </div> -->

  <form class="addListing">
    <h2 class="add-heading" id="heading-one">Add a new listing</h2>
    <h3 class="details-heading" id="heading-two">DETAILS</h3>

    <select class="category form-select" id="categories" name="Select category">
      <option value="cat0">Select Category</option>
      <option value="cat1">Tops</option>
      <option value="cat2">Bottoms</option>
      <option value="cat3">Outerwear</option>
      <option value="cat4">Footwear</option>
      <option value="cat5">Tailoring</option>
      <option value="car6">Accessories</option>
    </select>
    <input class="form-input item-name form-end" id="name-item" type="text" placeholder="Item name" required />
    <select class="form-select" id="des-select" name="Select designer">
      <option value="des0">Select Designer</option>
      <option value="des1">Nike</option>
      <option value="des2">Off-White</option>
      <option value="des3">Givenchy</option>
      <option value="des4">Adidas</option>
      <option value="des5">Champion</option>
    </select>
    <input class="form-input item-size form-end" id="enter-size" type="text" placeholder="Enter Size" />
    <div class="note" id="des-note">
      <p class="note">
        <em><strong>Please select a designer from the drop down.</strong>
      Please email<br />
      help@grailed.com if the designer you are trying to add does not<br />
      exist</em
     >
    </p>
   </div>

   <h3 id="color">COLOR</h3>
   <input
    id="des-color"
    class="form-input form-start"
    type="text"
    placeholder='Designer color name, i.e."Frozen Yellow"'
   />
   <h3 id="condition">CONDITION</h3>
   <select
    class="form-select"
    id="conditio-select"
    name="select condition"
    id="condition"
   >
    <option value="none"></option>
    <option value="new">New/Never Worn</option>
    <option value="gently">Gently Used</option>
    <option value="used">Used</option>
    <option value="very worn">Very Worn</option>
   </select>
   <h3 id="desc">DESCRIPTION</h3>

   <textarea
    id="input-desc"
    class="description"
    placeholder="Retail Price, Condition, Measurements, Shipping Policy, Link to Retail Page, etc"
   ></textarea>
   <h3 id="payment">PAYMENT</h3>
   <h5 id="tips"><a href="">Pricing tips --></a></h5>

   <input
    id="input-price"
    class="price form-input form-start"
    type="number"
    placeholder="Price (USD)"
   />

   <h3 id="shipping">SHIPPING</h3>
   <h5 id="ship-tips">
    <a href="">Shipping tips --></a>
   </h5>

   <p class="shipping-desc" id="ship-desc">
    Shipping costs are dependent on the service used as well as the
    size/weight of the package and the destination. Most services have an
    online tool for calculating the shipping costs in advance. Once a buyer
    has paid, it is the seller's responsibility to complete and pay for the
    shipment.
   </p>

   <div class="country">
    <label for="U.S">United States</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="20" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   <div class="second-col">
    <label for="canada">Canada</label>
    <input class="canada" type="text" placeholder="20" />
    <input class="canada" type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   <div class="country">
    <label for="UK">United Kingdom</label>
    <input type="text" placeholder="30" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   <div class="second-col">
    <label for="europe">Europe</label>
    <input class="europe" type="text" placeholder="30" />
    <input class="europe" type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   <div class="country">
    <label for="aus/nz">Australia/NZ</label>

    <input type="text" placeholder="10" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   <div class="second-col">
    <label for="asia">Asia</label>
    <input class="asia" type="text" placeholder="20" />
    <input class="asia" type="checkbox" />
   </div>
   <div class="country">
    <label for="other">Other</label>

    <input type="text" placeholder="25" />
    <input type="checkbox" />
   </div>

   <h3 class="photos-heading">PHOTOS</h3>

   <div class="orig-grid">
    <div class="images">
     <div class="image-upload pic-one">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img class="pic-image" src="upload-image-big.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload top-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload top-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload top-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload top-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload bottom-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload bottom-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload bottom-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
     <div class="image-upload bottom-row">
      <label for="file-input">
       <img src="upload-image.png" alt="" />
      </label>

      <input id="file-input" type="file" />
     </div>
    </div>
   </div>
   <button class="publish" type="submit">PUBLISH</button>
  </form>

  <footer class="footer">
   <div class="footer-links">
    <a href="">ABOUT</a>
    <a href="">HELP & FAQ</a>
    <a href="">TERMS</a>
    <a href="">ACCESSIBILITY</a>
    <a href="">JOBS</a>
    <a href="">IOS APP</a>
    <a href="">ANDROID APP</a>
   </div>

   <div class="footer-socials">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook-official"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube-play"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin-square"></a>
    <p class="copyright">Grailed © 2020</p>
   </div>
  </footer>
 </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think you should "break" your layout into pieces to make this work.
You should have a parent wrapper that decides in which direction display its children, in a row if the screen is large and in a column if the screen is reduced.

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="child-1"></div>
    <div class="child-2"></div>
    ...
    <div class="child-n"></div>
</div>
```

Let's say that row is just a container with display:flex and its base direction is flex-direction:row

```
.row {
    display: flex;
}
```

Now you need to visualize what elements need to be placed into this container, so since you said you need your 2 selects on the left and your 2 inputs on the right you have to wrap them in 2 container that are the children of the said parent row.

```
 <div class="row">
     <div class="child-1">
         <select-1>
         <select-2>
         ... description ...
     </div>
     <div class="child-2">
         <input-1>
         <input-2>
     </div>
</div>
```

Then you just need to change the direction of the row based on your media query.

```
@media screen and (max-width: 992px) {
  .row {
    flex-direction: column;
  }
}
```

and that's it

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So basically remove my grid layout and change it to flexbox?

Comment: You can try with other approaches, but imagine a grid layout like a table.. For small screen you should render vertically every row of your table, and that's not a table anymore. You could keep the display: grid in a desktop layout and change it to display block in small screen so every "cell" gets 100% width and renders correctly